# How do I solve this 3 x 3 system of non-linear equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I have to solve this problem, but I am stucked

$$y1 = \frac{x1}{x1 + x2} $$

$$y2 = \frac{x1 +x2}{x1 + x2 +x3} $$

$$y3 = {x1 + x2 +x3} $$

How do I solve for x1, x2, and x3?

The best I coud do is

$$y2y3 = {x1 +x2} $$

In this part I am stucked, how do I get the x1?

The answer is $$x1 = {y1y2y3} $$
$$x2 = {y2y3}-{y1y2y3} $$
$$x3 = {y3}-{y2y3} $$

Comment: isn't linear. . .

Comment: how do you know is not linear? and how can I solve it? any particular technique?

Comment: *linear* is an specific math technical term

Comment: It's linear if rewritten properly. Sub $y_2y_3=x_1+x_2$ into first equation to get $x_1=y_1y_2y_3$. Proceed to $x_2$ and $x_3$

Comment: **Hint:** Insert the exression for $y_3$ (third equation) into the second equation. Then solve the second equation for $x_1+x_2$. Then insert the expression for $x_1+x_2$ into the denominator of the first equation. Solve the first equation for $x_1$

Comment: hey @A.S. how do you rewrite to get that? s'il vousplait

Comment: Multiply first and second equation out. Boom - linear in $x_i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y_2 = \frac{x_1 +x_2}{x_1 + x_2 +x_3}= \frac{x_1 +x_2}{y_3}$$

$$y_1 = \frac{x_1}{x_1 + x_2}= \frac{x_1}{y_2y_3}$$

Comment: i.e. $x_1+x_2=y_2y_3$ and $x_1=y_1y_2y_3$ . . cool!

Comment: Oh I see thank you for answering

Comment: @Learner you are welcome